# How to get Jenkins to not use Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, gradle

I use Gradle rather than Maven. How do I get our Jenkins continuous-integration server to *not* use Maven? I've told Jenkins about Gradle and Jenkins uses it to build the project. Jenkins then insists, however, on rebuilding the project using Maven even though I've removed everything from the project-configuration having to do with Maven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work fine. Just please make sure that:

1. Your Jenkins job is a 'free-style software project':
   [image: job creation screen]
2. You have properly installed and configured Jenkins Gradle plugin.
3. You have 'invoke Gradle script' as the build step:
   [image]

Comment: Images got garbled when inserted in the post -- please right click on them and 'open in new tab' or equivalent. This is first time I'm posting image on SO -- sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: When I created the project, I intended to use Maven -- so I created it as a maven2/3 project. Is there any way to redo that decision?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. Have a look at [this SO questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636312/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-jenkins-free-style-job-to-a-multi-configuration-job) and [this answer from Jenkins project lead](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/changing-type-of-a-job-td372042.html).

Comment: Artur, I created a new, free-style project to work around the issue. Thanks.