# How create and configure a new Jenkins Job using groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

There are a lot of examples of groovy scripts (http://scriptlerweb.appspot.com/catalog/list) however I have found no examples of new job creation. Is there a good example online of how one should do this?

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8803743/2051952) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10413936/creating-a-jenkins-environment-variable-using-groovy) for some insight.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure or Create hudson job automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886892/configure-or-create-hudson-job-automatically)

Answer (score 13):

Create **Pipeline script from SCM** job:

```
import hudson.plugins.git.*;

def scm = new GitSCM("git@github.com:dermeister0/Tests.git")
scm.branches = [new BranchSpec("*/develop")];

def flowDefinition = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScmFlowDefinition(scm, "Jenkinsfile")

def parent = Jenkins.instance
def job = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob(parent, "New Job")
job.definition = flowDefinition

parent.reload()
```

Another example: https://github.com/linagora/james-jenkins/blob/master/create-dsl-job.groovy

Comment: How do you add credentials to the git checkout?

Comment: I have SSH keys and known_hosts in .ssh directory in jenkins user profile. You may try to use the second constructor: new GitSCM([new UserRemoteConfig('ssh://example.com', null, null, 'jenkins-ssh-credential')],
[new BranchSpec('*/develop')], false, null, null, null, null)

Comment: https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.java#L193

Answer (score 6):

The Jenkins plugin  [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) can add steps into jobs to create/modify existing jobs.

Here is the example from the plugin's web site, that creates a job for each branch in a git repository:

```
def project = 'quidryan/aws-sdk-test'
def branchApi = new URL("https://api.github.com/repos/${project}/branches")
def branches = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(branchApi.newReader())
branches.each {
    def branchName = it.name
    def jobName = "${project}-${branchName}".replaceAll('/','-')
    job(jobName) {
        scm {
            git("git://github.com/${project}.git", branchName)
        }
        steps {
            maven("test -Dproject.name=${project}/${branchName}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Given that you have an XML string containing the config.xml for the new job, the following groovy script will do what you want.

```
import jenkins.model.*

def jobName = "my-new-job"
def configXml = "" // your xml goes here

def xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( configXml.getBytes() )

Jenkins.instance.createProjectFromXML(jobName, xmlStream)
```

For more details see the [API Docs](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html)

Comment: Using XML is the thing I'm trying to avoid. It just makes the groovy code harder to read and maintain.

Comment: This creates a job at the top level.

Answer (score 3):

```
def jobDSL="""
node {
  stage("test"){
   echo 'Hello World'
  }
}

""";
//http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-cps/index.html?org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsFlowDefinition.html
def flowDefinition = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition(jobDSL, true);
//http://javadoc.jenkins.io/jenkins/model/Jenkins.html
def parent = Jenkins.instance;
//parent=Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("parentFolder/subFolder")
//http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-job/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/job/WorkflowJob.html
def job = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob(parent, "testJob")
job.definition = flowDefinition

job.setConcurrentBuild(false);

//http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/branch-api/jenkins/branch/RateLimitBranchProperty.html
job.addProperty( new jenkins.branch.RateLimitBranchProperty.JobPropertyImpl
    (new jenkins.branch.RateLimitBranchProperty.Throttle (60,"hours")));
def spec = "H 0 1 * *";
hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger newCron = new hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger(spec);
newCron.start(job, true);
job.addTrigger(newCron);
job.save();


Jenkins.instance.reload()
```

Comment: Works fine for me. It seems the API has changed since, I had to add third parameter to constructor: ` (new jenkins.branch.RateLimitBranchProperty.Throttle (60,"hours",true)));`