# Is it possible to download and configure jenkins with a script?

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I want to develop a continuous integration with one or many scripts locally and then on a server.

For that I need Jenkins. I installed jenkins in a docker container, but would it be possible to configure it with a script so that the configuration can be used on any computer that runs it? When I talk about configuration, I'm talking about jenkins jobs and plugins.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a configuration management tool like chef or ansible to install and configure in automated way. If using chef you can use the community [cookbook](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/jenkins). If you are only looking for creating jobs automated way check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963309/how-create-and-configure-a-new-jenkins-job-using-groovy?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Similar way you will be able to create groovy script to install plugins as well.

Also take a look at this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1056410/Setup-Configure-Jenkins-For-Your-Team-in-Automated)