# Can I use Jenkins CLI or some groovy scripts to create a new job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Can I use Jenkins CLI or some groovy scripts to create a new job?
This job can be copied from the previous one but the svn repo isn't the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure or Create hudson job automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886892/configure-or-create-hudson-job-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

There is a job-dsl plugin which allows you to create new jobs with groovy script

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, [see](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+all+projects+in+a+View)  you can use groovy for this