# Jenkins: Can I Generate groovy script from existing Job?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a job in Jenkins and want the groovy script for the same? Is there a way I can do that?

I have created a Job using Jenkins, like add shell Command, Sync from repo,etc. Now I wish to have groovy script for the same, but I dont want to go to the trouble of writing the entire thing again. Is there something like Export to .groovy?

P.S. I am not sure of the correct tags.

Comment: you question is too ambiquous.. could you please eloborate on what you need. you groovy script console to test incase you need to execute groovy scripts on your job.

Comment: @DevD updated question with additional info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to copy your configuration using Groovy script to create a new job or to persist.

Below Links are helpful for clone/ copy and create jobs using groovy script.

http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/How-to-Copy-Clone-a-Job-via-Groovy-td4097412.html

[Can I use Jenkins CLI or some groovy scripts to create a new job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975266/can-i-use-jenkins-cli-or-some-groovy-scripts-to-create-a-new-job)

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+all+projects+in+a+View

In case you want to persist your Job, always backup your resources file such as config.xml, jenkins.xml,etc..

you can recreate job from config.xml which holds all your job configuration

Comment: jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com link dead

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/convert-to-pipeline#). It seems to be appropriate for your purpose. Though it has some restrictions for plugins in your jobs that are not capable of Pipeline syntax. Anyway, it could be useful for code generation.