# Import crontab jobs into jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cron

I have some jobs on crontab and I would like to import all of them to jenkins.
Is there a nice elegant way to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You should check - [Configure or Create hudson job automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886892/configure-or-create-hudson-job-automatically).

Jenkins CLI exposes a way to [update job configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/309218/how-can-i-modify-a-jenkins-job-configuration-programatically-without-a-restart).  You may retrieve job definition and then update the job's config.xml with same cron notation and script