# How do I create a new project in Jenkins using Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am trying to create a new project in jenkins using groovy. Therefore I'd like to use jenkins script console. The script works fine but if you're looking at the corresponding configuration file the tag `<actions/>` is missing. Due to the missing tag the project isn't building. The following code works ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886892/configure-or-create-hudson-job-automatically)) for me but I don't want to copy another job just to get it works.

```
def jenkins = hudson.model.Hudson.instance
def template = jenkins.getItem("MyTemplate")
def job = jenkins.copy(template,"MyNewJob")
job.save()
```

That's my actually script.

```
//Get instance of Jenkins
def parent = Jenkins.getInstance()

//Define a job name
def jobName = "Job"

//Instantiate a new project
def project = new FreeStyleProject(parent, jobName);

//Set a description for the project
project.setDescription("Just a placeholder for a description")

//Create a parameter for the project
def parameterDefinitions = new ArrayList<ParameterDefinition>();
def name = "ParameterOne"
def defaultValue = "1"
def description = "Just a placeholder for a parameter description"
parameterDefinitions.add(new StringParameterDefinition(name, defaultValue, description) )

//Create a job property for the project
def jobProperty = new ParametersDefinitionProperty(parameterDefinitions);

//Adding and saving the job property to the project
project.addProperty(jobProperty)
project.save()
```

The corresponding config.xml is looking like that:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <description>Just a placeholder for a description</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
      <parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>ParameterOne</name>
          <description>Just a placeholder for a parameter description</description>
          <defaultValue>1</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
      </parameterDefinitions>
    </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
  </properties>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>false</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders/>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

The right form would be:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
   <actions/>
    <project>
      <description>Just a placeholder for a description</description>
      <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
      ...
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually if you restart Jenkins, the job should be successfully created. If you don't want to restart Jenkins, just call *reload* to reload configuration.

Adding following line of code to the end of your groovy script will solve the problem:

```
parent.reload()
```

Comment: I do not know why it works. The configuration file is still missing the tag '<actions/>' but the project can be built. I was sure that it was not working when I restart jenkins manually, but now it works.